# Neo4j nodes are showing up under the 'n' variable when I'm providing specific variables in curl

Tags: curl, neo4j, cypher

Here is the statement I am sending through curl:

```
{
    "statements" :[
        {
            "statement":   "CREATE (matrix1:Movie { title : 'The Matrix', year : '1999-03-31' }) CREATE (matrix2:Movie { title : 'The Matrix Reloaded', year : '2003-05-07' }) CREATE (matrix3:Movie { title : 'The Matrix Revolutions', year : '2003-10-27' }) CREATE (keanu:Actor { name:'Keanu Reeves' }) CREATE (laurence:Actor { name:'Laurence Fishburne' }) CREATE (carrieanne:Actor { name:'Carrie-Anne Moss' }) CREATE (keanu)-[:ACTED_IN { role : 'Neo' }]->(matrix1) CREATE (keanu)-[:ACTED_IN { role : 'Neo' }]->(matrix2) CREATE (keanu)-[:ACTED_IN { role : 'Neo' }]->(matrix3) CREATE (laurence)-[:ACTED_IN { role : 'Morpheus' }]->(matrix1) CREATE (laurence)-[:ACTED_IN { role : 'Morpheus' }]->(matrix2) CREATE (laurence)-[:ACTED_IN { role : 'Morpheus' }]->(matrix3) CREATE (carrieanne)-[:ACTED_IN { role : 'Trinity' }]->(matrix1) CREATE (carrieanne)-[:ACTED_IN { role : 'Trinity' }]->(matrix2) CREATE (carrieanne)-[:ACTED_IN { role : 'Trinity' }]->(matrix3)"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, I've provided unique variables or identifiers but once they are sent to neo4j, they all show up under some 'n' variable. This is making it a bit tough for me to manipulate and work with the data in neo4j.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: here is a sample query to find all the actors that acted in John Wick.

```
match (n:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(n:Movie {title:'John Wick'}) 
return n.name
```

EDIT 2: Let me elaborate on what i've done thus far.

In curl, I've posted the command above to generate all of the nodes and relationships for the Matrix.

After doing that, I go into Neo4j and look at what has been sent and the tabular format is shown below:

[image: neo4J screenshot]

You'll see that every node falls under the `n` variable.

Comment: If my answer isn't satisfactory, can you provide an example of a query that's tough for you to work with? This seems like more of a misunderstanding of what variables are and how they are used in Neo4j.

Comment: Updated, this is my first week using Neo4j so there could be a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to the variables such as `matrix1` and `keanu`?

Variables are not stored in the database, they are local to your query, and even then they can go out of scope if queries are separated by WITH clauses and the variable isn't brought over.

When you talk about an `n` variable, that's probably a new variable you introduced in a query to match on data in the database. Again, the variables you introduce are only in scope within queries. If you don't like using `n`, use a different variable.

EDIT

Let's take a look at that example query:

```
match (n:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(n:Movie {title:'John Wick'}) 
return n.name
```

The problem with this one is you've introduced a variable `n`, but you're using it for both the :Actor and the :Movie in the match, so it won't work (it's highly unlikely you're using a node that's both labeled as :Actor and :Movie with the title 'John Wick', and has an :ACTED_IN relationship to itself).

You'll need to use different variables for different nodes in your matches. Simply using `m` for the variable on the :Movie node will be enough to make this work.

And if `n` and `m` are too concise for you, use different variables:

```
match (actor:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(johnwick:Movie {title:'John Wick'}) 
return actor.name
```

Comment: yes, those are the variables i'm referring to. that's the thing, i've never introduced the variable `n` i'm not sure where it is coming from, it must be the default variable number. This is causing me issues since I have **Actors** and **Movies** in my data set and I can't properly query the data set since they have the same variable name.

Comment: You are in control of what variables you use in your query. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: As far as your second edit with `MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 25`, what this is asking is: match on all nodes of my database and bind them to a variable `n` (this is like a column alias), then return 25 of them. They will appear under a column named by the variable you used to match them, in this case, `n`.

Comment: That's much better, thank you. I'm still a bit confused as to why my data isnt organized by variable and they are all shown under the variable `n`.

Comment: No problem. You may want to ensure you've read through the [developer's guide](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/), and I think you'll find the [Cypher ref card](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/) to be invaluable as a reference.

Comment: Wow, that is perfect. Bookmarked. I'm surprised my professor decided not to provide something similar

Comment: Definitely clue him into this, nobody should be introduced to Neo4j, let alone given homework or project work, without the basic documentation and language reference. Also make sure you take advantage of tutorials and example graphs offered in the neo4j browser.

Comment: It's like in program code when you access data in memory and put it int local variables. Then that in-memory data has also no clue about your local variables.